# how do I get this :through?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join

so I have these relationships:

a location:

```
has_many :services
has_many :products, :through => :services
```

a product:

```
  has_many :services
  has_many :locations, :through => :services
  has_many :add_ons
```

and a service:

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :location

has_many :service_add_ons
has_many :add_ons, :through => :service_add_ons
```

a service_add_on:

```
belongs_to :service
belongs_to :add_on
```

How can I write a :through that will return a location with it's products and each products add_ons?
so far I have:

```
wants.json { render :json => @location.to_json(:include => {:products => {:add_ons}}) }
```

which is obviously not working.  What can I do to change this and make it work?

Comment: has_many :services
  has_many :locations, :through => :services
  has_many :add_ons... I added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
wants.json { 
  render :json => @location.to_json(:include => {:products => {:include => :add_ons}}) 
}
```

Comment: I didn't think to try and nest the include! It works perfectly though!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use

```
:include => {:products => :add_ons}
```

Comment: that didn't work, perhaps I should have incluced this:
wants.json { render :json => @locations.to_json( :include => [:products => :add_ons] )  }... I added that to the question too

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english :S

I think you have an error here:

a service_add_on:

```
belongs_to :service

belongs_to :add_on
```

add_on must belongs_to service_add_on and not contrary